# How to choose specific versions of packages to download using conda?

Tags: python, package, anaconda, conda

I am trying to install a specific package version and not quite sure how to access a specific version. When I type conda install SomePackage it just downloads the latest default. How can I choose specific versions?

Currently I want this package GDAL 2.2.4 I see it listed here:
https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/gdal/files

But how do I use the conda prompt to download that specific version?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

According to Anaconda documentation you should do:

conda install package=version ,like:

```
conda install scipy=0.15.0
```

Check the documentation case you have mode doubt: https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html

Or maybe the problem is the version of the package.

Answer (score 0):

It's the same if you are building using using an environment.yml file. This environment.yml downloads the java 1.8 conda package, and the pip pyspark package.

```
  name: my-conda-env
  channels:
      - defaults
  dependencies:
      - python=3.6
      - pip
      - ipython
      - jupyter
      - openjdk=8.0.152
    - pip:
      - pyspark
```

Please note this configuration (conda java + pip pyspark) is useful if you're building and deploying a pypi packages (instead of conda environments) to prebuilt docker containers set up for spark already.